# After reading a file how to read line from a such postion (java)

Tags: java, string, file, position

This code can read many files and display them in a textarea.

For example :

...........> 12 16 17 18

...........> 15 17 ab cd

...........> ad 2g at bc

I want to read files but only after the position of character = 12.
This is the code I'm using.

```
 FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
    File folder = new File("D:/bcc/");
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line = null;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while (null != (line = bufferedReader.readLine())) {
    lineCount++;

    if (1000 != lineCount) {

    jTextArea1.append(line +"\n");
    }
    }
    }
    }


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    if (null != bufferedReader)
    try {
    bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear (to me) what you are trying to achieve. Skip "12" ?

Comment: i mean that i want to read line from the carater number 12.

Comment: Do all files contain a character number 12 ? Are there any content before character number 12 ?

Comment: no i mean the position of character is 12

Comment: So, you basically want to skip the 12 first characters of each file and read all the rest ?

Comment: of each line in all files :)

Comment: And you have all of the above code, but you can't figure out how to skip 12 characters ???

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first 12 characters from each line, you could use the **[`substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)** method of String.

Replace:

```
jTextArea1.append(line + "\n");
```

with:

```
jTextArea1.append(((line.length() > 12) ? line.substring(12) : line) +"\n");
```

**EDIT**:
Lines with length < 12 are printed out exactly as they appear.

Comment: bah problem :java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -12

Comment: I am still not sure, that this address your real problem. It might help if you gave us some examples of input-lines and desired output-lines.

Comment: input :                                                             L010 ---> (186251084) 10 09 3b 44 16

L010 <--- (186251096) 10 7b 85 03 03 16

                                                                             output :                                                                    10 09 3b 44 16                                                                                             10 7b 85 03 03 16

Comment: The error you are getting means that there are empty lines in your files. I updated my answer so as to take lines with less than 12 characters into account (those are printed as is).

Answer (score 0):

use `substring` method in java

e.g.

```
String sCurrentLine = "Your String";
sCUrrentLine = sCurrenline.subString(sCurrentline.indexOf("firstCharcter")+12);
```